# Can't create a project Laravel 5.4 with composer

Tags: webpack

I go to desktop/Code and then I use this commands to install composer:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-
setup.php');"

php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') ==='669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa035516074
2ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 
'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Next i try to install laravel following this steps: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

But when i do:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

My laravel version is 5.2 and not 5.4

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead mark an answer as accepted when eligible. This will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was solved.**

Composer can't create a Laravel project with version 5.4 cause i have **old version of php**.

To fix this problem do:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

And then

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

You can check your php version with:

```
php -v
```

Now you can create the project ;)